# elasticsearch query and cURL in PHP no results

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch

i tried to using PHP to execute the  cURL request and separate curl var_dump output into different variables?but didn't shown anything in php and No errors in PHP logs.

**Here is my code:**

```
$url='curl -XGET <my_url>:9200/logstash-index-*/_search?pretty -d \'
 {

    "size": 0,
     "aggs" : {
        "langs" : {
                "terms" : { 
                   "field" : "name" ,
                    "size": 0
                          }
                  }
             }
  }\'';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
ob_start();
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($data);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently mixing up two things here, the linux cURL command and the php_curl commands.

Here is a linux command to type in a bash / sh for example :

```
curl -XGET <my_url>:9200/logstash-index-*/_search?pretty -d '
{
"size": 0,
 "aggs" : {
    "langs" : {
            "terms" : { 
               "field" : "name" ,
                "size": 0
                      }
              }
         }
}'
```

And here is the same example using php_curl :

```
$url = '<my_url>:9200/logstash-index-*/_search?pretty';
$data = array(
    "size" => 0,
    "aggs" => array (
        "langs" => array (
                "terms" => array ( 
                   "field" => "name" ,
                    "size" => 0
                )
        )
    )
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error());
curl_close($ch);
//var_dump($return);

//return is json_encoded, you can decode it to have an array
$array_return = json_decode($return,true);

$aggregationsArray = array(); 
foreach($array_return['aggregations']['name']['buckets'] as $person) 
{
    $aggregationsArray[$person['key']] = $person['doc_count']; 
}
var_dump($aggregationsArray);
```

Edit1 : Post data must be json_encoded
Edit2 : Return is json_encoded, decode it with json_decode
Edit3 : Add customized loop

Comment: got the error : error:
  root_cause:
  - type: "parse_exception"
    reason: "failed to parse search source. source must be an object, but found [VALUE_STRING]\
      \ instead"
  type: "search_phase_execution_exception"
  reason: "all shards failed"
  phase: "query"
  grouped: true
  failed_shards:
  - shard: 0
    index: "logstash-index-2016.05.23"
    node: "SQeFot_gTj-mqe5G-6kGSQ"
    reason:
      type: "parse_exception"
      reason: "failed to parse search source. source must be an object, but found\
        '... (length=550)

Comment: Try to json_encode the $data array when passing threw CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

Comment: it's work and no error but can i just only  to get all key list  to array ?

Comment: Can you provide your current return please ?

Comment: string '{
  "took" : 114,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 100,
    "successful" : 100,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1627997,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "hostname" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "jack",
        "doc_count" : 275006
      }, {
        "key" : "arron~son",
        "doc_count" : 132978
      }, {
        "key" : "mary",
        "doc'... (length=12244)

Comment: var_dump didn't return all , it's end " "doc'... (length=12244)"

Comment: Your return is JSON encoded, you can decode it to have an array with `$array_return = json_decode($return,true);` for example.

Comment: now,after JSON encoded , $array_return looks like ,

Comment: Array
( [took] => 102
    [timed_out] => 
    [_shards] => Array
        (
            [total] => 100
            [successful] => 100
            [failed] => 0
        )
    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1627997
            [max_score] => 0
            [hits] => Array
                ()
        )

Comment: [aggregations] => Array
        ( [name] => Array
                (
                    [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
                    [sum_other_doc_count] => 0
                    [buckets] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => arron-CA
                                    [doc_count] => 275006
                                )

Comment: [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => jack-one~NY
                                    [doc_count] => 132978
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [key] => mary-CA
                                    [doc_count] => 122051
                                )
.......

Comment: Ok is it not what you wanted to have ?

Comment: i want to get key and  doc_count ,it's will be looks like :   $aggregationsArray = array( "arron-CA" => "275006", "mary-CA" => "122051", ... );

Comment: It's now just a matter of parsing the array and create the array you want ;-)

Comment: Something like `$aggregationsArray = array(); foreach($array_return['aggregations']['name']['buckets'] as $person) { $aggregationsArray[$person['key']] = $person['doc_count']; }`. I edited my answer to see better.

Comment: Let me know if everything is ok for you or if there is more issues ? Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem ;-)

Comment: julqas,do you know how to solve the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908307/elasticsearch-query-malformed-no-field-after-start-object-in-php