# elasticsearch bool query error in php client

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch returns me `[_na] query malformed, no field after start_object` error  when trying to look up entries using the following query. The field localtime is a new field of documents and exist in every document.

php code,

```
$qryurl = '<myurl>:<myport>/index/_search?pretty';
$data = array(
"query" => array(
  "bool" => array(
    "must" => array(
      "range" => array(
        "localtime" => array(
          "from" => "2016-06-15T17:43:04.923Z",
          "to" => "2016-06-17T17:43:04.923Z",
          "include_lower" => "true",
          "include_upper" => "true"
        )
      ),
      "term" => array(
        "query" => "1.2.3.4",
        "fields" => array("ip")
      ),
      "query_string" => array(
        "query" => "*up*",
        "default_field" => array("_all")
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Why does this error appear?

anyhelp will be appreciated  ! thanks!

Comment: In "term", you have not the same thing between curl and php_curl. Try to put `" term" => array("query" => "1.2.3.4", " fields" => array("ip"))`.

Comment: Julqas, now print success,but how to parse the data to array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bool/must` clause must be a pure array not an associative array:

```
$qryurl = '<myurl>:<myport>/index/_search?pretty';
            $data = array(
                "query" => array (
                    "bool" => array (
                      "must" => array(
                          array(
                             "range" => array ( 
                                  "localtime"  => array (
                                      "from" =>"2016-06-15T17:43:04.923Z",
                                       "to" => "2016-06-17T17:43:04.923Z",
                                       "include_lower" => "true",
                                       "include_upper" => "true"
                                  )
                             )
                          ),
                          array(
                              "term" => array(
                                  "ip" => "1.2.3.4"
                              )
                          ),
                          array(
                              "query_string" => array(
                                  "query" => "*up*",
                                  "default_field" => "_all"
                              )
                          )
                      )
                    )

        )
    );
```

Comment: error message :[term] query does not support array of values

Comment: because you miss to add  query_string ,i tried to add but got err ""[bool] query does not support [1]","" when add this array('query_string' => array('default_field'=>"_all",'query'=> "*up*"))

Comment: I didn't miss since it wasn't present in your initial PHP code. Now I've added it. Try again.

Comment: got the same error :"[bool] query does not support [1]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115067/discussion-between-matt-crawfoord-and-val).